# Python 3 is giving me errors that I can't resolve

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Heres the code:

```
import turtle
import math

def drawTree(segments,size):
    """
    :param segments: refers to number of extensions from the previous
    :param size: refers to the length of the initial extension
    """
    if (segments < 0.0 | size < 0.0):
        print("Invalid Input")
    elif (segments == 0 | size == 0):
        pass
    elif segments > 0:
        i = 1
        for i in range(6):
            turtle.down()
            turtle.forward(size)
            turtle.back(size)
            turtle.right(60)
            i -= 1
            if segments != 0:
                size *= (1/3)
                turtle.forward(size)
                turtle.back(size)
                segments -= 1
                drawTree(segments, size)
def main():
    drawTree(1, 200)
    input("Press ENTER to exit")

main()
```

Heres the error list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MATTHEW/PycharmProjects/snowflake/snowflake.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/MATTHEW/PycharmProjects/snowflake/snowflake.py", line 33, in main
    drawTree(1, 200)
  File "C:/Users/MATTHEW/PycharmProjects/snowflake/snowflake.py", line 14, in drawTree
    if (segments < 0.0 | size < 0.0):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'int'
```

The errors don't really haven an explanation. In fact, this code was running fine until I added the last for loop, and, for some reason, it stopped.

Comment: Obviously you have made changes that broke the code. `segments < 0.0 | size < 0.0` means `segment < (0.0 | size) < 0.0` and the parenthesis means bitwise or of `0.0` and `size` which is nonsense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean operators vs Bitwise operators](//stackoverflow.com/q/3845018/90527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator. For a boolean OR, use the [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
if (segments < 0.0 or size < 0.0):
```

and

```
elif (segments == 0 or size == 0):
```

The `|` operator is a [bitwise operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations); it applies boolean logic to individual bits of integers.